# Using shell to draw a table of information

Tags: shell, awk

I got the following data in a txt file,

```
Apple:Fruit:20:30
Leek:Vegetable:40:50
```

In a form where, (item description):(item category):(qty):(price). How to draw a table using shell script. Having an output

```
Item Description           Category          Qty       Price        Total Sales
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apple                      Fruit             20         $30.00         $600.00
Leek                       Vegetable         40         $50.00         $2000.00
```

where Total sales is equal to qty x price. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could get you started

```
awk '{printf "%-27s%-18s%-11s$%-14.2f$%.2f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$3*$4}' FS=: foo.txt
```

Result

```
Apple                      Fruit             20         $30.00         $600.00
Leek                       Vegetable         40         $50.00         $2000.00
```

Comment: where to specify the file? Under FS?

Answer (score 2):

I would perform the calculating and currency formatting in awk, use column for the table spacing and then sed to add the line:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '
    BEGIN {print "Item Description","Category","Qty","Price","Total Sales" }
    { $(NF+1) = $3*$4; $4 = sprintf("$%.2f", $4); $5 = sprintf("$%.2f", $5); print }
' file.txt |
column -s: -t | 
sed '1{p;s/./-/g}'
```

```
Item Description  Category   Qty  Price   Total Sales
-----------------------------------------------------
Apple             Fruit      20   $30.00  $600.00
Leek              Vegetable  40   $50.00  $2000.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with awk, but it's much cleaner and simpler (and reliable) to use column to calculate the column sizes:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" ; print "Item description:Category:Qty:Price:Total sales"}
    {printf("%s:%s:%i:$%.2f:$%.2f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$3*$4)}' INPUTFILE | column -t -s:
```

I'm leaving the printing of the separator line to you (e.g. capture `column`s output with awk, after the first line calculate the length of `$0`, etc.)

Comment: How to print the seperator? Tried putting \n then followed by dashes but it did not get me far.